# if div includes letter then add class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript or jquery

I have 6 divs with the IDs letter0, letter1, letter2, letter3, letter4, and letter5 . They all contain 1 letter.

I want to check all 6 divs for the character lastUsedLetter . If one of the divs includes lastUsedLetter (which is just 1 character) I want to add class .color to that specific div.

Thankyou. (also , .addclass works if the div already has an ID im assuming .. it wil then just have both)

here is my code, it is very long. there might be another problem with it.

I know this will be incredibly annoying to  read, I just started with javascript. Sorry

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var words = ["ladder", "horse", "house", "car"];
        var guessedLetters = [];
        var letter0 = $('#letter0');
        var letter1 = $('#letter1');
        var letter2 = $('#letter2');
        var letter3 = $('#letter3');
        var letter4 = $('#letter4');
        var letter5 = $('#letter5');
        var letter6 = $('#letter6');
        var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
        var startButton = $('#startButton');
        var gameModule = $("#gameModule");
        var guessedWord = $("#guessedWord");
        var wholeWord = $("#wholeWord");
        var usedLetters = $("#usedLetters");
        var guessCount = $("#guessCount");
        var guessNumber = 0;
        var wordLength = randomWord.length;
        console.log(wordLength);



        startButton.click(function () {
            startButton.css('opacity', '0');
            startButton.css('cursor', 'default');
            usedLetters.css('opacity', '.8');
            guessCount.css('opacity', '.8');
            for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {

                guessedWord.append("_ ");

            }
            for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
                wholeWord.append("<div id='letter" + [i] + "'>" + randomWord.charAt(i) + "</div>");
            }

        });

        document.onkeydown = function (e) {

            var keyPress;

            if (typeof event !== 'undefined') {
                keyPress = event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e) {
                keyPress = e.which;
            }

            guessedLetters.push(String.fromCharCode(keyPress));
            lastUsedLetter = guessedLetters.slice(-1)[0];
            lowerLastUsedLetter = lastUsedLetter.toLowerCase;
            usedLetters.append(lastUsedLetter.toLowerCase() + ", ");
            guessNumber++;
            guessCount.text("Guess count: " + guessNumber);



            document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(e => e.textContent.includes('lastUsedLetter') ? e.classList.add("color") : false);
            return false;   // Prevents the default action
        };


    });

</script>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you attempted any code for this?

Comment: I'm just trying things from google, Im very new to javascript. I cant paste my whole code but this is the last part of my hangman game. I'm trying to make guessed letters from opacity 0 to opacity 1 if they are guessed

Comment: Trust me, Your code is not very long

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to get the `div` and using the `textContent` property see if the `div` includes the word using `includes` method. Add class to the div which returns true using `element.classList.add()`

```js
var lastUsedLetter="sfsdf";
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(e => e.textContent.includes(lastUsedLetter) ? e.classList.add("color") : false);
```

```css
.color {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="letter0">
  lastUsedLetter </div>
<div class="letter1">
  dsds </div>
<div class="letter2">
  lastUsedLetter </div>
<div class="letter3">
  lastUsedLetter sfsdf fsfsd </div>
<div class="letter4">
  dsdsdsd</div>
<div class="letter5">
</div>
```

Comment: didn't work, I updated my main post with my code. I'm starting to think I'm just doing something else wrong.

Comment: .includes is checking for string called lastUsedLetter and in your code i can see that this is a variable. give the exact string for it to check for

Comment: Check edits to see how variables can be searched for

Comment: Uh, its still not working. I wish I could explain the problem better. When I console log last used letter Im getting the letter i'm looking for and its the last thing in the code so i'm not sure why its not matching properly ..

Comment: oh ok I think I see the problem . letter0, letter1 etc don't actually seem to be strings... log shows this w.fn.init {} , im calling the div not the string in it.. im not sure how to .. innerhtml?

Comment: innerHTML returns undefined  ... the divs look like this <div id="letter0">l</div>

Comment: elaborate please

Comment: I honestly cant even explain the problem. I'm sorry haha. I'll just keep messing around with it.

Comment: honestly how am I supposed to help then?

Comment: I'm saying I appreciate your help so far but I don't think i'm well versed enough in javascript to even explain my problem. I don't want to waste any more of your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190222/discussion-between-depetrify-and-ellipsis).